# How can I access local directory in Autohosted Apps

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I have a file in D:/Temp. How do I access it from an autohosted app. Is it possible? Should I give some extra permissions?

The error Shows:

```
    Server Error in '/' Application.
    Access to the path 'D:/<filename>' is denied.
```

Thanks

Comment: This does not answer your question but you should know that Autohosted Apps were deprecated recently and you should you Provider Hosted Apps insted: http://blogs.office.com/2014/05/16/update-on-autohosted-apps-preview-program/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot access the local file system in an auto-hosted app. When you deploy the app package, Microsoft provisions a site in Azure to host the app. The hosting is a complete "black box". You don't know anything about, or have access to anything on, the hosting machine.

With that said, you should not be investing any time in building auto-hosted apps. Microsoft will be turning off hosting for these apps sometime in the next six months. See the link in Vardhaman's comment.